# Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result q

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result

I get the error when trying to run this:

```
<?php
function kishvoteCount() {
global $wpdb;
 $query = "SELECT c_alef FROM {$wpdb->prefix}kishvote";
 $posts = $wpdb->get_results($query) or die(mysql_error());;
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($posts))

{

    echo('<PRE>');

    print_r($row);

    echo('</PRE>');

}
}
?>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

UPDATE

when try with var_dump($posts) returned

```
( array(6) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2254 (1) { ["c_alef"]=> string(1) "3" } [1]=>   object(stdClass)#2265 (1) { ["c_alef"]=> string(1) "3" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#2256 (1) { ["c_alef"]=> string(1) "3" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#2251 (1) { ["c_alef"]=> string(1) "0" } [4]=> object(stdClass)#2261 (1) { ["c_alef"]=> string(2) "10" } [5]=> object(stdClass)#2264 (1) { ["c_alef"]=> string(1) "7" } }
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($posts)` to see what's being returned. You're using WordPress's own database functions, and I suspect it handles all the database calls for you. The documentation has a few useful examples: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: @andrewsi i try with var_dump and update results to question

Comment: Yep. You don't need to use `mysql_fetch_array` at all. Change that loop to `foreach ($posts as $row)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop through it to fetch the data from the DB, as the `$posts` variable is already in the right format.

Just loop through it like this:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    var_dump($post);
}
```

As @andrewsi mentioned, Wordpress takes care of all the DB handling.